# sending email using play 1.2.4 framework

Tags: playframework-1.x

I am trying to send email using gmail smtp server on play 1.2.4 framework but email is being printed in the counsel only.
Can some one can please tell how to make it work.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify that, but you're testing it most probably in `DEV` mode. In such case `smtp.host` in `application.conf` is set to `mock`, you need to change it.

This is [described in documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/emails#smtp)

Comment: thank u very much Marcus
I had read those documentation but after you send me,I again went through it..I forgot to comment those line...so its working now...thank u a lot....

Comment: as this is the correct answer, can you mark it correct to make it easier for others to find